# AJAX send request get method, display HTML page

Tags: javascript, ajax

How can I send request using GET method in AJAX and display in my HTML page, this is html

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                @*<li class="list-group-item"><i class="mi mi-Calculator"></i>Process Payroll</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item"><i class="mi mi-Airplane"></i>Vacation Leave</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item"><i class="mi mi-Badge"></i>Maternity Leave</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item"><i class="mi mi-CashDrawer"></i>Close HR Period</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item"><i class="mi mi-CallForwardRoaming"></i>Change Shift</li>*@
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

How can I apply GET method in AJAX? I'm still learning using JavaScript thank you so much

Comment: I wanted to use AJAX, GET method and display the result via the HTML above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another example. you can append your data if you have more than one entry.

```js
let outputText = '';
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    success:
      function(response) {
      response.forEach(function(element,index){
       var divHtml = index + ' ' + element.name + '<br />';
        outputText += divHtml;
                if(response.length - 1 == index)
            $('.content').html(outputText);
        });
      }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">

</div>
```

Comment: it works!! how can I enclose the element.name a clickable link?

Answer (score 1):

here is the example

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
    success:
      function(response) {
      console.log(response)
         document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0].innerHTML  = response.title
      }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">

</div>
```

Comment: $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    url: 'url',
    success:
        function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            document.getElementsByClassName("list-group")[0].innerHTML = response.data.title    
        }
});

when I check the console 

Object
data: Array(2)
0:
FeatureID: "003924"
FeatureName: "Self Service"
Link_URL: "url"
__proto__: Object

I wanted to get and display only the FeatureName and display to my html page like this

Most Used Services
Leave
Vacation Leave
Close

Comment: it means u are*getting an array in response if you want to display only first featureName of Array you can use this. document.getElementsByClassName("list-group")[0].innerHTML = response.data[0].FeatureName; 

if you want to display all array use foreach like below example.